# Every simply connected, bounded, Lipschitz domain in the plane is the interior of some Jordan curve?

Tags: general-topology

Let $U$ be a nonempty, **simply** connected, bounded, Lipschitz open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is there exists a Jordan curve $\gamma$ where int($\gamma$) = $U$? Here, int($\gamma$) denotes the bounded component of $\mathbb{R}^2 - \gamma$.

It is intuitively very plausible since the boundary of $U$ is locally a (Lipschitz) path in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but I cannot provide a rigorous proof.

Added: by a Lipschitz open set, I mean an open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ such that for each $z \in \partial U$ there exists a Lipschitz map $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $r>0$ such that $ B(z,r)\cap U = \{(x,y): y>f(x)\} \cap B(z,r)$ (up to changing the x-axis and the y-axis).

Edited: connectedness is replaced by simple connectedness. THANKS FOR THE COMMENTS.

Comment: Don’t you need $U$ to be simply-connected, by Jordan-Schoenflies? (see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoenflies_problem )

Comment: Incorrect in this form. Consider e.g. the interior of the unit circle with a circle of radius 1/2 removed.

Comment: Your definition of Lipschitz open set appears flawed: You have $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $x \in \partial U \subset \mathbb R^2$, and then you write $f(x)$ which makes no sense.

Comment: Oh, I changed the symbols to prevent confusion. Thanks. Also, thanks for the suggestions - I was indeed imagining the situation where $U$ is simply connected.